# Able to hit endpoint using POSTMAN but not using PYTHON

Tags: python, post, postman, google-colaboratory

I have a POST endpoint as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/*****/***********/orders/k137982151
```

I get a success response from this on POSTMAN.

I generated a python code snippet using POSTMAN as follows:

```
import requests

url = "http://localhost:8080/*****/***********/orders/k137982151"

headers = {
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "********-*****-***-****-********"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers)

print(response.status_code)
```

I get a 404 as a result. I have tried using urllib too. I still get 404. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you still get a 404 if you use `requests.post(url, headers=headers)`?

Comment: Yes. It still returns a 404. P.S. I'm using Google Colaboratory. Do you think that might be creating a problem?

Comment: Have you tried posting to it from postman itself

Comment: Yes. It works perfectly.

Comment: Most likely. Your endpoint is self-hosted (see `localhost`) and I _believe_ PostMan requests originate from your local machine. From what I understand of Google Colaboratory, their notebooks are hosted on a Google server somewhere, which wouldn't be able to access your `localhost`. I suspect that if you save your code to a file and run it locally, it'll probably work.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Let me try this, and update you guys.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. :)